# What size oven/range based on new gas line's permitted BTUs?

Tags: oven, natural-gas, stove, gas-burner

We recently had a gas line run to our kitchen from the side of the house. We just got the rough-in work approved on our permit (had a plumber install the line) and we are approved for future stove @ 35,000 BTUs and oven at 20,000 BTUs.

2 Questions:

1. Does this mean that there are up to 55,000 BTUs for a range if we stick with an electric oven?
2. Does this mean we have to buy a range small enough so that the total burners on the stove total less than 35,000 BTUs? Or is it just a matter of efficiency if we had a range drawing more than 35,000 BTUs?  (For example, the range that we really like, if you had all the burners on, it would be 71,000 BTUs, but we would rarely have more than 3 burners on and would almost always be below 35,000.)

TIA

Comment: Did the plumber just run the line down the wall and stop, or are there two connections stubbed out for a range and an oven?  Looking at [a chart](http://snowcrest.net/thriftysupply/pdf/NAT-LP-PIPE-SIZE.pdf), I guess it wouldn't matter.  Even if it was broken out into two connections, each connection could still have almost the full capacity (1/2 pipe can handle 108K BTU at 10 feet long).

Comment: The plumber ran the line into the cabinet near the future gas range/oven and ended it with an analog gauge. Sorry for the delay. I responded days ago but it didn't take for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the way gas capacity is calculated (pipe size and length), the capacity of the line running to the kitchen is capable of the full BTU load plus any loss for additional fittings required to get to the individual appliances.  I wouldn't be surprised if the pipe run to the kitchen could support something in the 100k btu range, but you would have to ask the plumber on that.  I'm sure it can support a single appliance at 55K.

Because permits differ from location to location, it might be a good idea to ask the plumber if there is an issue with just running one appliance, but from a capacity point of view, there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @jphil618 thanks for the reply. But when you say it can support a single appliance at 55k, what is the standard basis for defining "support"? if every burner is on and the burners total 71k, I guess that would not work (or at least there would be hampered gas flow?)? or is there an equation to define "support" in consideration of the fact that not everyone ever really has all their burners on or runs them all on high at the same time?

Comment: I'm actually not sure how a gas range is "rated".  I don't know what percentage of burners they use for gas requirements.  The plumber that ran the gas line should be table to tell you the maximum BTU it will support since he would know the pipe size, fitting count and run length.  I assume the actual capacity is higher than you or the permit specified, but the plumber would know how much for sure.